# Rate Limit for only success requests (Laravel 9)

Tags: php, laravel, rate-limiting

Is there anyway to apply rate limiting to the route but for only success responses. Like for example if user sends request to `send/code` endpoint 5 times and if all of them was successful then block the user to send request again. But if 2 of them was unsuccessful (like validation error or something) but 3 was successful then user should have 2 more attempts for the given time.

I know rate limiting checks before request get executed, then block or let the user to continue. But is there anyway to apply my logic or should I try to approach differently?

Comment: Laravel's rate limiting is applied to all requests, regardless of whether they are successful or not.

Comment: @francisco I already said that ***I know rate limiting checks before request get executed, then block or let the user to continue***. Just asking to find out best approach for this case (Using `Rate Limiting` is not required).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would probably need to make your own middleware, but you can extend the `ThrottleRequests` class and just customize how you want to handle responses:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests;
use Illuminate\Support\Arr;

class ThrottleSuccess extends ThrottleRequests
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @param  array  $limits
     * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
     *
     * @throws \Illuminate\Http\Exceptions\ThrottleRequestsException
     */
    protected function handleRequest($request, Closure $next, array $limits)
    {
        $response = $next($request); // call the controller first

        if ($response->statusCode === 200) { // only hit limiter on successful response
            foreach ($limits as $limit) {
                if ($this->limiter->tooManyAttempts($limit->key, $limit->maxAttempts)) {
                    throw $this->buildException($request, $limit->key, $limit->maxAttempts, $limit->responseCallback);
                }
    
                $this->limiter->hit($limit->key, $limit->decayMinutes * 60);
            }
        }

        foreach ($limits as $limit) {
            $response = $this->addHeaders(
                $response,
                $limit->maxAttempts,
                $this->calculateRemainingAttempts($limit->key, $limit->maxAttempts)
            );
        }

        return $response;
    }
}
```

Then add your middleware to `Kernel.php`:

```php
    protected $routeMiddleware = [
        // ...
        'throttle.success' => ThrottleSuccess::class,
        // ...
    ];
```

Then use it in a route like the original throttle middleware:

```php
Route::middleware('throttle.success:5,1')->group(function () {
    // ...
});
```

Note: you may have to override `handleRequestUsingNamedLimiter` if you want to return a custom response built from `RateLimiter::for`, I have not done anything for that here.

Comment: ooo that's genius. I always thought to call the throttle before the controller hit. Didn't realize you could call it after. Thanks!

Comment: And now your controller will be executed every time, even when the throttle is hit, that's genius) 
You should put `$response = $next($request);` between exception and `->limiter->hit`.

Comment: @AdamM. it all depends on their use case. Maybe they want it to be able to validate every time even if the user is throttled?

Answer (score 0):

This is source code

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\RateLimiter;

class CodeZiDotProTestRateLimit extends Controller{
public function test_rate_limit_only_success(Request $request){

    // Step 1: Validate the request data
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'name' => 'required|string',
        'email' => 'required|email',
        'password' => 'required|min:8',
    ]);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return response()->json(['errors' => $validator->errors()], 422);
    }

    // Step 2: Apply rate limiting to this controller action
    $key = 'test_rate_limit_only_success_by_ip_'.request()->ip();
    if (RateLimiter::tooManyAttempts($key,10)) {
        return response()->json(['errors' => 'You have made too much in a short time. Please wait after 1 minute'], 422);
    } else {
        RateLimiter::hit($key, 60);
    }
}
```

}

Suppose my URL is Example.com/test_Rate_Limit_only_success.

In this example, when a user sends a request to the system, the application will still validate the request (and if there are errors, the user will send unlimited requests). In the case of valid data, the rate limiting part will start working.